# How to change backgroung of selected cells?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

How to change backgroung of selected cells in jTable?

I have already written table-rendering, but it allocates all row, and do not visible what kind of cell selected now.

```
public class MyTableRanderer extends DefaultTableCellHeaderRenderer{

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable jtable, Object obj,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {
        setText(obj.toString());

        if(isSelected){
            setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
            setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        } else {
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        }

        return this;
    }

}
```

EDITED:

```
public class MyTableRanderer extends DefaultTableCellHeaderRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable jtable, Object obj,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {
        setText(obj.toString());

        Component cell = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                jtable, obj, isSelected, hasFocus, row, col);


        if (isSelected) {
            setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
            cell.setBackground(Color.green);
            setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        } else {
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        }

        return this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to change backgroung of selected cells in jTable?
>
> I have already written table-rendering, but it allocates all row, and
>   do not visible what kind of cell selected now

then is required to test both methods `if (isSelected & hasFocus) {`

Answer (score 1):

Try to insert this in your `getTableCellRendererComponent` function, to target a specific cell :

```
Component cell = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(
   table, obj, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
if (isSelected) {
   cell.setBackground(Color.green);
}
```

Comment: I tried, but anyway allocated all row.
See my edited code.

Comment: Then try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6868323/1715716 . By the way your question is a little bit a duplicate.